# R: plm individual and time fixed effects but no other regressors

Tags: r, plm

I want to run a regression including only time and individual fixed effects (i.e. no other right-hand side variables).

I try to do this with `plm`:

```
plm(y ~ -1,data=data, effect="twoways", model="within")
```

However, the syntax is not correct, nor does it work to just suppress the `-1` from the model formula.

The error message is: `Error in uniqval[as.character(effect), , drop = F] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions`

What is the correct syntax with plm for a regression of `y` on only time and individual fixed effects?

Thanks!

Comment: you should include a reproducible example!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me to be not supported by `plm`. Use a `lm` approach instead:

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld)

# not possible with plm
mod <- plm(inv ~ -1, data=Grunfeld, model="within", effect = "twoways")

# use lm instead
mod2 <- lm(inv ~ -1 + factor(firm) + factor(year), data=Grunfeld)
```